# Get data from store - RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I've started learning RTQ Query. For example i have following setup in **service**.ts:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const dataApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'reducerApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'someApiUrl',
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getByName: builder.query({
      query: (name: string) => name`,
    }),
  });

export default dataApi;
```

and then i use useLazyQuery hook in **triggerComponent**.tsx to get the data on button click and get the argument from input like this:

```
const TriggerComponent = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string>('');
  const { useLazyGetByNameQuery } = dataApi;
  const [trigger] = useLazyGetByNameQuery();

  const handleClick = () => {
    void trigger(inputValue);
  };

return (
   <input
     label="Search"
     value={inputValue}
     onChange={(event) => setInputValue(event.target.value)}
   />
   <button onClick={handleClick}>
     Search
   </button>
)
```

and then I want to access this data in another component, but here comes my problem. I don't know how to get fetched data from created store. In ReduxDevTools I can see that data is fetched correctly of course. Any advices?

Answer (score 2):

You have few options:

1. Call the same query in the component where you have this data. And enable caching by providing a second argument, [see docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery).
2. Or create selector and select from query result. There are examples in [docs](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced#selecting-users-data)

Comment: So I need to pass the argument from input value somehow, for example by putting it in the store?

Comment: I don't get your question, can give some example